# SQLAlchemy not finding correct results

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I am currently developing a web application using flask and postgres for the backend. In this, I have a Church model with the fields `lat, lng` and `rofrs_value`. To find the churches and their coordinates in pgAdmin, I run this command: `select lat, lng, rofrs_value from church order by rofrs_value desc limit 10`. This results in 10 results shown here:[Query result with 10 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JGBH.png). On the backend, I have this endpoint and method to retrieve the rofrs scores:

```
@bp.route("/flood/rofrs/", methods=["GET"])
def risk_rofrs():
    lat = request.args.get("lat", default=None, type=float)
    lon = request.args.get("lon", default=None, type=float)
    return church_rofrs(lat, lon)

def church_rofrs(lat, lon):
    ROFRS_SCORES = {
        0: 0,
        1: 10,
        2: 50,
        3: 100,
        4: 200
    }
    prob_level = db.session.query(Church.rofrs_value).filter(
        Church.lng == lon,
        Church.lat == lat
    ).all()
    if len(prob_level) != 0:
        print("The building is a church with a ROFRS of " + str(prob_level[0][0]))
        return str(ROFRS_SCORES[prob_level[0][0]])
    else:
        print("Entity with given coordinates not found. Returning zero.")
        return "0"
```

When I visit this url

```
http://localhost:5000/risks/flood/rofrs/?lat=52.364253408754152&lon=1.237043090299609
```

I get a result of 0 and the message saying that no entity was found with the given coordinates even though pgAdmin shows that there is a row in the database with those coordinates.

Does anybody know what may be causing SQLAlchemy not to find the matching row? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you find anything using select lat, lng, rofrs_value from church where lat=52.364253408754152 and lon=1.237043090299609;

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. When I execute that query it returns the expected result. This led me to find the solution. For some reason, the `type=float` when taking in the arguments from the request was causing the problem. Switching it to `type=str` seems to have fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You dont have to define get method explicitly, GET method is assigned by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found thanks to @galaxyan is to switch the `type=float` to `type=str` in the risk_rofrs method. With that the method returns the expected response.